# java get ipv4 address on local network

Tags: java, serversocket

I want to get ipv4 adress and i am writing this code:

```
System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
```

it is returning different ip address. I explained my problem in image:

I want to take green ip address but it's giving to me red ip address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`InetAddress.getLocalHost()` is apparently returning the address for "Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network". You seem to want the address for "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi".

Iterate through the available network devices on your computer using `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`, checking the device name via `NetworkInterface#getDisplayName()`.

Once you found the interface you want, use `NetworkInterface#getInetAddresses()` to obtain the addresses provided by that interface. Iterating over this will give you access to the address you desire.

See [Listing Network Interface Addresses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

Comment: Firstly thank you for your explain. But i have one more question. How can i get ip address of currently using. Because of computer can has many ip more than one but it's using only one. How can i get this?

Comment: @GürkanUçar If you have a separate question, please post as a new question. If you feel it's part of this question, please edit your post to include those details (so people don't have to look through comments for answers)

Comment: It's "using" all of them. What do you mean by "using"?  You either have to know which interfatce you're interested in, or perhaps you want to know which interface an existing socket connection is bound to.  In the latter case, call getLocalSocketAddress on the socket.